# Problems with using Compound microscope and telescope in the place of each other

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, telescopes, microscopy

Compound microscope is used to see magnified image of tiny objects. Whereas telescope is used to see distant objects' magnified image. I wonder can we use telescope to see small objects placed close to objective lens? And can Compound microscope be used to see celestial objects? They both have two convex lenses the only difference is the focal length and diameter of lenses. So what will be the problems in interchanging their uses?